# Change body background at each section on scroll

Tags: html, angular, sass

Change the background image for each alternate section so that when the user will see the background image sticks and content above it scrolls.

[This](https://yesmadam.com/pages/welcome) is the exact example of what I am trying to achieve.

I have taken three sections and I want the first two to have another background to the body and after that another background.

I have not achieved yet anything but I also don't know what to call this feature.

Comment: check out the parallax effect:  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the task correctly, the main thing you need is `background-attachment: fixed;`. It makes the background image scrollable.

Check out the stackblitz example. It's all in the `app.component.css` file.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppesf3

Answer (score -1):

Please check this. This may help you. Hear is the example of change color on scroll.
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/1e8k9q8b/)

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
    $(".header").addClass("active");
} else {
    //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
   $(".header").removeClass("active");
}
});
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to add jQuery to the Angular projects. And the task itself can be done with css and a bit of js.

Comment: If you fell that I'm wrong or you have better option, Then you are on right platform, Please post your answer. And I'll give +1 if it's correct. :)